# How to activate this JQuery on different event?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have two combo boxes. One combo box contain values that became variables to do AJAX post. The result then inserted into the second combo box.

I use `onchange` in the first combo box. However, I'd alos like to do it when body `onload`

Without rewrite the function, how do I solve my issue?

The combo box jQuery :

```
$('#tl_dept').on('change', function() {
    var dept_val = $(this).val();
    var opsi = "";
    var divs = "";
    $.ajax({
        type        : "POST",
        dataType    : "json",
        data        : { x : dept_val },
        context     : $(this),
        url         : "<?php print base_url(); ?>xxx/some_function",
        success     : function(response){
            //success script
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `}).trigger("change");` on the last line..this way the change event will be called on onload..make sure it is inside document ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I use onchange in the first combo box. However, I'd like to do it when
>   body onload.

You do not need this.

You can use `.trigger` function which executes all handlers and behaviors attached to the matched elements for the given event type.

```
$('#tl_dept').on('change', function() {
    var dept_val = $(this).val();
    var opsi = "";
    var divs = "";
    $.ajax({
        type        : "POST",
        dataType    : "json",
        data        : { x : dept_val },
        context     : $(this),
        url         : "<?php print base_url(); ?>xxx/some_function",
        success     : function(response){
            //success script
        }
    });
}).trigger('change');
```

Comment: woah.. that was fast. Thank you so much.

Comment: @ashura91, you should make sure that the combo box's first value is not empty. Becuase then `onchange` will be triggered, the selected value is being stored in `dept_val` variable. So it will be null because of triggered event, as the user won't have selected any value of the combo.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this function should be inside a `$(function() { .... })` so it first fires when the document is ready...

Comment: yes @LinkinTED, I think Alexandru's solution will make a recursive `onchange`. I need to try this way although.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay, no.`on` method only attaches a `change` event handler to the select DOM element and then trigger this event using `.trigger` function.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay when `onload` the combo box has a default value

Comment: @ashura91, if the combo box has a default value, Alexandru's solution will be helpful. :-)